# Усовершенствованный шифр Цезаря с++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, файлы

Написал код для шифрования методом Цезаря. Все работало, но 
при считывании файла дублировало последний символ при  выводе на экран. Аналогичные вопросы возникали и у других, как писали это проблема с `feof()`.

Переделал код, компилируется, но ничего не выводит, подскажите в чем проблема.

```
int main() {
    FILE * Ptr;
    Ptr = fopen("D:\\7.txt", "r");
    int i = 0, d = 0;
    char l , a[20];
    printf(" Vhidni dani:\n\n ");
    /*
    while (!feof(Ptr)) {
        fscanf(Ptr, "%c", & l);
        a[i] = l;
        printf("%c", a[i]);
        i++;
        d++;
    }
    */
    while( fscanf(Ptr, "%c", &l) == 2 ) {
        a[i]=l;
        printf("%c", a[i]);
        i++;
        d++;
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < d - 1; i++) {
        if (!isdigit(a[i]))
            a[i] += 7;
    }
    printf("\n Zashifrovane povidomlennja:\n\n ");
    fclose(Ptr);

    FILE * Ptr1;
    Ptr1 = fopen("D:\\SHIFR1.txt", "w");
    for (i = 0; i < d - 1; i++) {
        printf("%c", a[i]);
        fprintf(Ptr1, "%c", a[i]);
    }
    fclose(Ptr1);
    getch();
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: да похожие ответы были, но код не работает

Comment: @craftyperson Вы должны проверить, открылся ли у вас входной файл или нет.

Comment: @craftyperson И данное условие неверное. while( fscanf(Ptr, "%c", &l) == 2 ) Вы должны сравнивать с 1, так как вы считываете только один объект.

Comment: я вас правильно понял:if (!(Ptr=fopen("D:\\7.txt","w")))
        {
         printf("Error! Cannot open file");
         getch();
         return 0;
        }

Comment: так проверять открылся ли?

Comment: если да, тогда не выбивает ошибку(

Comment: все то самое, что и было

Comment: @craftyperson Смотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, вы не проверяете в программе, открылся ли у вас файл, или возникла какая-нибудь ошибка.

Во-вторых, данное условие в if предложении

```
while( fscanf(Ptr, "%c", &l) == 2 ) {
```

некорректно, оно всегда будет ложным, так как вы указали только один элемент для считывания в форматной строке. Должно быть

```
while( fscanf(Ptr, "%c", &l) == 1 ) {
```

Также так как у вас массив имеет фиксированный размер, то вы должны в этом цикле проверять, не вышли ли вы за границу массива

```
while( i < sizeof( a ) && fscanf(Ptr, "%c", &l) == 1 ) {
```

Также не понятно, почему у вас в цикле стоит условие

```
i < d - 1
```

Должно быть

```
for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
```

так как вы считали `d` символов. И вместо проверки с использованием `isdigit`, лучше проверять с использованием функции `isalpha`, если вы хотите шифровать только буквы.

Comment: я извиняюсь если вопрос глупый, но правильно я делаю?

Comment: if (!(Ptr=fopen("D:\\7.txt","w")))
        {
         printf("Error! Cannot open file");
         getch();
         return 0;
        }
    while( fscanf(Ptr, "%c", &l) == 1 )
{
    a[i]=l;
    printf("%c", a[i]);
    i++;
    d++;
}

Comment: @craftyperson Да, это уже лучше.:)

Comment: ничего не изменилось

Comment: @craftyperson Как ничего не изменилось? У вас в цикле считывания стоит предложение  printf("%c", a[i]); Оно печатает введенные символы?

Comment: я об єтом и говорю, вроде бі должно, а ничего(

Comment: @craftyperson Также вы должны убедиться, что файл не использует UNICODE.

Comment: я недавно только начал программировать, что такое unicode? обїясните, пожалуйста, что єто и как проверить его?

Comment: @craftyperson Замените в этом предложении  printf("%c", a[i]); спецификатор формата га %d и посмотрите, что будет выводить на экран.

Comment: вернее віводит только, vhidne povidomlennya:и zashifrovane povidomlennya

Comment: @craftyperson  Ну у вас не задана русская локаль. Поэтому будут выводиться латинские буквы. Занесите в файл какой-нибудь латинский текст и проверьте, работает ли программа как есть .:)

Comment: в файле, "we have 10 parrots", такой подойдет?

Comment: он біл изначально там

Comment: @craftyperson Слушайте, если вы сделали, как я сказал, то файл должен считываться. Вставьте внутрь цикла отладочную печать, например, puts( "O'k" ); чтобы убедиться, что управление попадает в цикл.

Comment: это потоковая функция? так ведь,просто не разбирал их, вот и спрашиваю. нет не работает.

Comment: @craftyperson Если вы сделали все так, как я сказал, то должно работать. Фраза "не работает" ни о чем не говорит. Если текстовый файл открывается, и он содержит текст, то он должен читаться. Все. Точка.

Comment: стоп, я извиняюсь

Comment: я не заметил, что в проверке открытия файла стои"=", а не "=="

Comment: файл не открываеться

Comment: @craftyperson Значит убедитесь, что он действиьтельно находится на диске D  в корневом каталоге.

Comment: нашел ошибку в условии открытия выхлдит, что и первый открывал для записи. поменял , но все то самое(

Comment: а файл в корне диска

Comment: @craftyperson Тогда если вы указали правильно имя, то он должен открываться. Это к программе уже никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: ясно, порубую еще раз

Comment: нет ничего( все без изменений

Comment: @craftyperson Что без изменений? Файл не открывается? Ну так создайте его заново с нужным именем.

Comment: уже делал, два раза

Comment: @craftyperson Я не знаю, почему у вас файл не открывается. Если указано правильное имя, и файл не открыт какой-нибудь другой программой, и у вашей программы есть права на доступ к файлу на чтение, то он должен открываться. Вы также можете создать файл в том же самом директории, где у вас запускается программа. Это к самой программе никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: ок, спасибо. прошу прощенияния, если задавал глупые вопросы

Comment: @craftyperson У вас на компьютере стоит UNIX-подобная операционная система?

Comment: @craftyperson Либо вы до сих пор не можете корректно написать открытие файла Дрожно быть if ( ( Ptr = fopen("D:\\7.txt","r" ) ) == NULL ) { /* error */ }

Comment: Вы были правы, огромное спасибо, буду разбираться)

Comment: @craftyperson В чем вы собираетесь разбираться?

Comment: в проходе до конца файла)